# Assembly macro check argument

Tags: assembly, macros

Well, a new strange problem occurred within assembly (especially tasm)

```
CheckInfo MACRO arr:REQ, length:REQ, arr_type := <l>
    mov bx, arr
    mov cl, length
    mov si, 1
    IF arr_type eq <x>
        inc si
    ENDIF
    mov a&arr_type, [bx]
ENDM
```

Just want to check whether arr_type equals to x. If yes then add to si a value of 1. Nothing else. But when I try to tasm it, then it throws an error

```
Illegal forward reference: L
Undefind symbol: L
```

But why? I just want to check whether two values are equal char by char or not

Comment: Weird : in EMU8086 it compiles fine, but TASM complains, mmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `IF arr_type eq <x>` ends up being expanded to `IF l req <x>` and in this context `l` is a symbol. If you want to compare them as characters you need to use strings and substitute `arr_type` into a string:

```
IF "&arr_type" EQ "x"
```

Note that this isn't actually a character by character comparison. The EQ operator compares unsigned integers, so the strings are converted to integers and then compared.